# Setting a max size when using Faster Jackson to deserialize an array

Tags: java, json, jackson, out-of-memory, jackson-databind

I have the code below where I am deserializing a JSON string with an object containing an array of custom objects.  We are using fasterxml.jackson.  We have seen cases where the number of items in the array is large enough to cause an `OutOfMemoryError` when deserializing.  What is the easiest way to enforce a max size on the number of items that can be serialized out of the array?  I am really looking to throw an exception or return an error in the case where the limit is exceeded.

```
class InputMessage {
    private final List<Action> actions;
    
    @JsonCreator
    public InputMessage(@JsonProperty("actions") final List<actions> actions) {
        this.actions = actions;
    }

    List<Action> public getActions() {
        return actions;
    }
}
```

All of the solutions I have seen thus far perform the size check on the list of items after it is done serializing into the java objects.  I'm interested in knowing how it can be done during serialization so don't consume excess memory on the JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I used to solve the problem.  The code has great performance because it checks the limit as it is parsing the input instead of instancing all of the items and potentially running out of memory.  This prevents a single JSON String from disproportionally consuming more memory.

```
/**
 * Custom deserializer used to convert a list of {@link Input}
 * into a list of {@link ConvertedInput}.
 */
static final class RequestItemsDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<List<ConvertedInput>> {

    // RFC 1149.5
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;
    private static final int INPUT_LIST_LIMIT = 1024;

    private static final ObjectReader READER = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(Input.class);

    public RequestItemsDeserializer() {
        this(List.class);
    }

    public RequestItemsDeserializer(Class<?> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public List<ConvertedInput> deserialize(final JsonParser jp, final DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        final List<ConvertedInput> convertedInput = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!jp.isClosed() && JsonToken.START_ARRAY == jp.getCurrentToken()) {
            for (int i = 1; !jp.isClosed() && (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY); i++) {
                if (i > INPUT_LIST_LIMIT) {
                    throw new RequestInputTooLargeException("\"input\":[...]",
                            "This request exceeded the item limit of " + INPUT_LIST_LIMIT + ".");
                }
                convertedInput.add(READER.readValue(jp));
            }
        }
        return convertedInput;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad the answer was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

`@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` annotations are part of the binding API, which implements & uses its own parsing logic that does not allow the custom conditions you want. You need to override parts of the parse.

For the arrays you want to limit, use a *custom deserializer*. You will want to extend [`StdDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer.html), and implement the `deserialize` method. This method will make use of Jackson's [Streaming API](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi) to process actual tokens of JSON like `{` or `[` or `"some string"`, and you will be responsible for allocating objects (or not).

Inside the `deserialize` method you don't have to parse `Action` objects by hand; you can still rely on the binding API by creating an `ObjectMapper` and then using `objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser, Action.class)`.

Refer to your custom deserializer class via [JsonDeserialize](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html):

```
public InputMessage(
    @JsonProperty("actions") 
    @JsonDeserialize(using = /* your class */)
    final List<actions> actions) {
```

Some searches for examples and guides:

- [Jackson "custom deserializer" "@JsonDeserialize"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Jackson+%22custom+deserializer%22+%22%40JsonDeserialize%22)
- [Jackson JsonParser deserialize array](https://www.google.com/search?q=Jackson+JsonParser+deserialize+array)
- [Jackson "jsonParser.nextToken()" END_ARRAY](https://www.google.com/search?q=Jackson+%22jsonParser.nextToken()%22+END_ARRAY)